# Get `dirname $0` of a KornShell script called by a symbolic link

Tags: shell, unix, ksh, symlink

I have a folder organization that looks like this:

```
link.sh
dist/MyApp-3.0.0/script.sh
dist/MyApp-3.0.0/lib/*.jar
```

The `link.sh` is a symbolic link to the KornShell (ksh) script `script.sh`. In the shell script, I want to call a Java program with following command:

```
java -cp lib/*
```

When I try to launch the application from the symbolic link, I get `ClassNotFound` because the relative path is resolved from the link base dir (this is normal).

Inside the shell script, how can I get the full path of the script (`<...>/dist/MyApp-3.0.0/`)? It will allow me to modify my Java call:

```
java -cp ${SCRIPT_DIR}/lib/*
```

Comment: You cannot with 100% reliability obtain the "full path to the running script" from shell code. You can get close, however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit: using readlink**

You can use readlink, and it boils down to:

```
SCRIPT_DIR=$(dirname "$(readlink -f $0)")
```

**Edit: without readlink**

```
if test -h $0; then
    symdir=$(dirname "$(ls -l $0 | sed -n 's/.*-> //p')")
    if [[ -z $symdir ]]; then
        symdir=.
    fi
    fullreldir=$(dirname $0)/$symdir
fi
script_dir=$(cd $fullreldir; /bin/pwd)
```

I misunderstood the location of the script, and had assumed that the directory of the script being invoked was in the directory structure of the target application, where the following would work:

```
SCRIPT_DIR=$(cd $(dirname $0); /bin/pwd)
```

Comment: doesn't work: it returns the link directory, not the script dir :/

Comment: huh... you need to make sure you're using `/bin/pwd` (the command), and not just `pwd` (the shell builtin) - /bin/pwd should return the resolved path

Comment: I've altered the answer significantly, with two mechanisms - one using `readlink`, and one using `ls` and `sed`, which is more suitable for systems like Solaris, that don't ship with readlink by default

Comment: The edit without readlink works fine, many thanks. I was hoping that it could be easier with a "dirname like" command. Regarding readlink, how can I introduce it in my ksh? The man returns something but if I execute your command line in the script.sh, I get the not found error.

Comment: readlink is a command that ships as part of gnu coreutils - you can ask the shell to find the command using `type -p readlink`, if it returns `readlink not found` then it means that the command is not present on your path or is not installed on your system. You should be also able to use the `locate readlink` command to determine where on your system the readlink command is installed

Comment: Ok, looks like readlink man is present but not the readlink command... Anyway, even if the solution without readlink is a bit long (I will have to copy paste it in all my shell scripts), it works fine. Many thanks Petesh.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the readlink function (man readlink)

my2c

Comment: I'm trying to get something totally within ksh, no dependencies. If it's not possible, I will create a link on the folder instead of putting it on the script itself: MyApp -> MyApp-3.0.0. Thanks though